# How to open a route in a new tab or window with Meteor iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Have a click event that renders an html print view of a form. Is there a way to have this route opened in a new tab?

I dug around on here but don't find anything that addresses iron router.

Answer (score 5):

You can just do:

```
window.open(Router.url(pathName, paramsObject, queryHashObject));
```

The only required argument is the path name.  The other two are for if the route requires Iron Router parameters or a query-string or hash, in which case the format is exactly as [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes).

Comment: Thanks, that was really close and helped narrow it down. In the end, I just left the path name in the window argument and viola! Code is: window.open("/cool-form-report/#{_id}/print")